# Correct format for one or many range_field in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a range_field that inside of a form_for and I am not sure how to correctly pass the values needed to the controller and to the database.

There does not seem to be very much information about range_field that I could find. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970360/rails-4-0-submiting-range-field-does-not-update-params) was the only question that was similar that I could find.

range_field(object_name, method, options = {}) public

I want it to save `:value, :food_id, :user_id, :vas_question_id` in a new vas_answer when I click Next. Do I need to utilize hidden_field to do this?

There could be 1-3 questions on each page. 
Would it be better/easier to save it as an array or as 3 separate answers?

Relevant code cut from my current view:

```
<%= form_for @answer do |answer| %>
  <% @foods.each do |food| %>       # there could be 1, 2, or 3 foods
    <h4 class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.6em; clear: both;"><%= @question.prompt_left %> <strong><%= food.name %></strong> <%= @question.prompt_right %></h4>

    <%= range_field :vas_answers, :value, min: 1, max: 500, step: 1, class: 'not-clicked', :food_id => food.id, :user_id => current_user.id, :vas_question_id => @question.order %>  

    # I saw :user_id => user.id on another question so I tried it, but I don't know what it is really doing

  <% end %>
  <%= answer.submit 'Next', :class => 'col-md-offset-9 btn btn-primary btn-surv' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class VasAnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @answer = VasAnswer.new(answer_params[:vas_answers])
    @q_num = params[:order]      # determine order of questions (not really relevant)
    @q_num = @q_num.to_i + 1
    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.save
        if @q_num < 25
          format.html { redirect_to vas_questions_url(@q_num) }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to demographics_path}
        end
      end
    end
  end

private
    def answer_params
      params.require(:vas_answers).permit(:value, :user_id, :vas_question_id, :food_id)
    end
end
```

Route:

```
  post   "vas_questions/:order" => "vas_answers#create", as: :vas_answers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be a little confused in your approach.  Rather than go through each line and explain the failures, I would suggest perhaps using a different approach involving forms and nested forms.  Check out the Rails Cast on the topic:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

It's an older topic but it should help you get the form structure straightened out a bit. He has an updated Cast on the subject, but you have to be a member to see it:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

I would say restructure your forms in that pattern, and come back with another set of questions.  Start with the simplest form of the structure, and get it working and then add complexity.

Hope that helps.

UPDATE: I saw your post on Reddit.  The fact that you appear to be a student at Chico State may be preventing people from wanting to "do your homework".  I tried to answer in a way that will get you to learn the Rails way, rather than solve the problem for you.